# how to overwrite an existing table row from the rest API output in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have some static html table rows with one column values.

I want to show them first with a loading icon and then would like to fire a rest call for each of the rows remaining values.

After i get the response for each of the row from the rest api, i would like to update the corresponding row in the table.

How would i do that in Angularjs? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Do you have some code to show?

Answer (score 0):

Just write a promise to call your rest api, then bind the data to the view on the promise success.If you are making individual calls for each rows, have each calls made on individual promises.

Comment: I am making individual rest calls for each of the row.. Do you have any sample code? Also, how to you link the table row with the corresponding rest call?

Comment: You can refer to these for sample code [angular $http call](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)
 and 

[promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

. Since you are firing individual rest calls for each row, whatever you are using to get the data fom the server for individual rows, can be used for linking the rows to the API call